# "Base constructors must all have the same return type" when extending Angular 14 FormControl

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm trying to extends the FormControl class in an Angular 14 project but i am always getting

> "Base constructors must all have the same return type"

here is my code:

```
export class DWFormControl<T, K> extends FormControl<T> {
  inputConfig?: K;

  constructor(
    value: FormControlState<T> | T,
    opts: FormControlOptions & {
      nonNullable: true;
    },
    inputConfig?: K
  ) {
    super(value, opts);
    this.inputConfig = inputConfig;
  }
}
```

this error disappear if i put any as a generics for FormControl like so:

```
export class DWFormControl<T, K> extends FormControl<any> {
  inputConfig?: K;

  constructor(
    value: FormControlState<T> | T,
    opts: FormControlOptions & {
      nonNullable: true;
    },
    inputConfig?: K
  ) {
    super(value, opts);
    this.inputConfig = inputConfig;
  }
}
```

but i would like to use the new features of typed forms that i will lose if i use any.

this error can be replicated also in the official angular stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Found a corresponding Github issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/47558

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same pattern as using in angular source code.
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/14.2.x/packages/forms/src/model/form_control.ts

```
export interface IEnhancedAbstractControlOptions {
  // custom stuff
  custom: boolean;
}

const defaultEnhancedAbstractControlOptions: IEnhancedAbstractControlOptions = {
  custom: false,
};

export interface EnhancedFormControl<TValue = any> extends FormControl<TValue> {
  custom: boolean;
}
type EnhancedFormControlInterface<TValue = any> = EnhancedFormControl<TValue>;

// Internal class, rip-off ɵFormControlCtor with enhanced typings
interface ɵEnhancedFormControlCtor {
  new (): EnhancedFormControl<any>;

  new <T = any>(
    value: FormControlState<T> | T,
    opts: FormControlOptions & { nonNullable: true }
  ): EnhancedFormControl<T>;

  new <T = any>(
    value: FormControlState<T> | T,
    validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | FormControlOptions | null,
    asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null,
    _opts?: Partial<IEnhancedAbstractControlOptions>
  ): EnhancedFormControl<T | null>;

  prototype: EnhancedFormControl<any>;
}

export const EnhancedFormControl: ɵEnhancedFormControlCtor = class EnhancedFormControl<
    TValue = any
  >
  extends FormControl
  implements EnhancedFormControlInterface<TValue>
{
  custom: boolean;

  constructor(
    // formState and defaultValue will only be null if T is nullable
    formState: FormControlState<TValue> | TValue = null as unknown as TValue,
    validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | FormControlOptions | null,
    asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null,
    _opts?: Partial<IEnhancedAbstractControlOptions>
  ) {
    super(formState, validatorOrOpts, asyncValidator);
    const { custom } = { ...defaultEnhancedAbstractControlOptions, ..._opts };
    this.custom = custom;
  }
};
```